# Tabular font size in LIPIcs class

Tags: tables, fonts, templates, document-classes, journal-publishing

I am using the class `lipics-v2021.cls` from [here](https://github.com/dagstuhl-publishing/styles/tree/master/LIPIcs/authors). I have noticed that changing the font size before a `tabular` has no effect, as it would normally have:

```
\documentclass{lipics-v2021}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        X
    \end{tabular}
    \tiny
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        X
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If I replace the class by, e.g., `article`, the second X is smaller, as expected. What's going on inside that class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class does

```
\let\@classzold\@classz
\def\@classz{%
   \expandafter\ifx\d@llarbegin\begingroup
     \toks \count@ =
     \expandafter{\expandafter\small\the\toks\count@}%
   \fi
   \@classzold}
```

so inserting `\small` into every cell  of every `tabular` and `array` this is a strange choice, especially as (unlike simply setting `\small` once at the start), it leaves the row spacing dependent on the current size (normal and tiny) in your example, which is why your X are not aligned,  but forces the font within the cell.

As that block of code does nothing else apart from that, this is clearly deliberate, I'd be tempted to remove it but as always with publisher's styles it may make sense to just go with the flow and do whatever they require.

[image]

```
\documentclass{lipics-v2021}
\makeatletter
\ifx\@classzold\@undefined\else
  %put it back
  \let\@classz\@classzold
\fi
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        X
    \end{tabular}
    \tiny
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        X
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd certainly not mess around with a journal or conference provided style, no matter how bad their choices are. I'm sure I'd never have found the culprint.